# Read content of cursor location in terminal/Shell

Tags: shell, terminal, text-cursor

I'm working on a unique project using terminal/Shell but I've hit a little bit of a roadblock I haven't been able to work around.

I want to be able to read the content of the location of the cursor.

For example, if the cursor is currently located on line 2, column 5 which contains an E, I want to be able to read that E and create a variable with it.

Comment: Do you mean a unix shell or a windows shell? This might be possible if you write a c-program that can interogate raw memory, but essentially,  a major project/headache. Maybe with Xwindows and a true xterm?. Sorry and Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

Can you explain what your project entails?  It might help if we knew what you're trying to accomplish.

No tools exist to do this in the shell, as far as I know.  To actually read a remote screen would require this as a feature of the remote terminal (or emulator).

Neither do any compiled language support this. All applications that appear to do this *fake* it by keeping an internal copy of what they *assume* is displayed on the screen.

Lookup the [curses](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curses_%28programming_library%29)* library for more information.  This toolkit allows a programmer to address the screen as a random accessible grid, and hides all of the updates to the actual terminal screen.

See also: [ncurses](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ncurses)

Comment: On that note, why not keep track of absolutely everything displayed to the screen, and then use a program to read a the file you are recording stuff to to get the character at such and such position from the end?